# Docker. How to make files outside from container available on Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, robotframework

I am running tests based on Robotframework.

I need to build container without tests ( container has to contain only needed soft and tools) and then use a mount point to make the tests available inside the container (using ***docker run -d -it -v "$(pwd)"/target:/app***) so that container won't actually contain any of the tests and won't need to be rebuilt after writing new tests.

It works on Ubuntu, but does not works on Mac. Is there a way how to run tests outside from container on Mac?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Does the docker container crash? Does it run the wrong files? Do you get an error, and if so, what is the error?

Comment: I also thought of the same question as @BryanOakley. Can you explain why this is not working?

Comment: @Bizmate, on Mac container does not see files inside volume, see empty folder.

Comment: If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker Engine daemon has only limited access to your macOS or Windows filesystem. Docker Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (macOS) or C:\Users (Windows) directory. So, you can mount files or directories on macOS using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

I was not able to see files because of I've created docker machine by running **docker-machine create default --driver xhyve --xhyve-experimental-nfs-share**.

When I've recreated by **docker-machine create default --driver xhyve --xhyve-experimental-nfs-share=true** everything is fine.